# Have Google Reader show entire Digg article?

Tags: google-reader, rss, feeds, digg

If you subscribe to a Digg RSS feed, I'm sure you are familiar with this problem. You can view the story, but then you have to click through to Digg.com, and then click again to view the actual content.

Is there a way to bypass this? So I can either click the link right in the RSS to go to the story, or ideally, just view the story in my RSS? Is there an actual digg sponsored one.

Edit: I don't want to use a different reader. Just a new rss link if possible.

Comment: Yes you can .Feed it through a Yahoo Pipe. From there you can modify it how you want. Going out now, so I do not have time to build one right now maybe someone will take the *hint*

Comment: Forget about Digg and start reading Reddit :P

Comment: I would like something like the iPad's Flipboard for an web application for this kind of fix

Answer (score 4):

So here are the options at your disposal because this is a very old problem

1. **Feeddit** - http://feeddit.com/

   Feeds are 100 stories long and has the actual link so you can skip past Digg and get directly to the story.
2. **A Yahoo Pipe**

   Either cloned or self made regex and mapping replacement modules. If you need assistance let me know otherwise I am just going to provide you with a clone [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=djWEb8tr3BGaBLLdBx2yXQ) or [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=953cf8d83df81a7bafcde079568e0eeb).
3. **R2-Digg2** - http://www.r2unit.com/digg/

   Lists all the feeds auto-created from the Digg API with direct links.
4. **User Scripts Redirects**

   Take the hassle out of getting a different RSS feed and just let the [script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/2569) do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at an experiment called **Readable Feeds**:
http://andrewtrusty.appspot.com/readability/

> Readable Feeds can filter out ads and other junk from your feeds so that you can concentrate on the content. **It can even repair crippled feeds that only show small excerpts instead of the full content, saving you the time and hassle of leaving your feed reader.**
>
> Readable Feeds is brand new and there is a good chance it may fail spectacularly on some feeds. Any and all feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

For *usability purpose*: their feed fetcher might be doing this for some specific websites (as Digg.com is a sort of link page, and it is highly subscribed)

Comment: No, this is a result of the RSS feed itself.